# C# Declaring local vs out of scope function variables and performance vs readability/robustness

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, scope, local-variables

I've been wondering how to deal with this issue for some time now and I can't find an elegant solution to it. I think some examples are the easiest way to understand the problem.

Let's say we have this code within a class and x and y need to start at 0 when their functions get called:

```
// here we have x as a local variable
private void functionX() {
    int x = 0;
    // ...
    // do stuff with x
    // ...
}

// here we have y as an out of function scope variable
int y;
private void functionY() {
    y = 0;
    // ...
    // do stuff with y
    // ...
}

public void update() 
{
    // this is slower because x gets a new instance every time functionX gets called    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        functionX();
    }

    // this is faster because y gets only one instance before the function ever gets called
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        functionY();
    }
}
```

I have tested this code and using the out of function scope variable instead of using the local variable yields better performance (albeit not by a lot in this example but there's a performance increase nonetheless). The downside is that you have to declare the function variable **outside** of function scope in order to get this performance gain which makes your code messier and more error prone.

This is only a very simple example but what happens if you have thousands of lines of code with tons of these kind of function variables and the performance gain from having them out of function scope cannot be ignored but the mess you make from having all these variables out of scope cannot be ignored either? Is there a solution to this problem or you will just absolutely have to make a choice between performance and readability/robustness?

**ps.** making either x or y static variables inside their functions does not work either when you have to construct multiple objects from the class they're in (all your objects will have a single instance of x and y for the whole program runtime)

Edit: simplified the code even more

Comment: Swap the order of functionX and functionY loops so you call Y first and re-test, I bet you will see that X becomes faster. Testing in artificial situations like this is hard to do correctly.

Comment: The only reason why the performance should be better for `functionY` is: there is only one assignment `y = 0`; In `functionX` is the assignment two times, because `int x;` already assign zero to `x` and then you assign it second time manually. And one more. the `y` variable is compiled with the class, but the `x` variable is compiled only on first use. Call `functionX` and `functionY` one more time before the loop, to compile the functions ahead.

Comment: The functions do nothing.  The example makes no sense to me.

Comment: Also how are you testing, are you in a release build with no debugger attached? if not the test is meaningless because the compromises the compiler has to make to get the debugger to work will greatly affect the results.

Comment: If you have thousands of lines of code constructed like `FunctionY` then you have much bigger problems than small performance differences.

Comment: "Slower because x gets a new instance" makes no sense really... The variable is an integer. There's no allocation going on

Comment: I actually like micro optimization questions, however there is nothing to optimize here :( Though on saying that, every variable you create in the scope of another method will be created on the stack, and will be an allocation and will take precocious CPU cycles. Yet making these Instance fields are a bad idea, you have stopped any chance of paralleling this.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I tested on debug mode initially but this is weird. On debug mode the out of scope variable solution is twice as faster as the local variable solution. On release mode the opposite is true, though the difference is much smaller. I don't understand this.

Comment: @TheGeneral "every variable you create in the scope of another method will be created on the stack, and will be an allocation and will take precocious CPU cycles" that's what I was thinking but apparently the compiler is doing some magic I don't understand on release mode.

Comment: @Devez your `functionY` actually prove this, because you are using an instance field, however there is not a lot to go on here. i suggest putting everything in the method, just `Parrallel.For` or taking your methods over to StackEchange Code Review for a real hoedown

Comment: @TheGeneral I think I see what you're going for. However I don't think the class variable is the problem here for parallelism. You can just lock until y gets set to 0, if parallel.for works in classic thread fashion. I will take a look at it later.

Comment: `I tested on debug mode initially` **Never** test performance on debug mode. It is a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

if it goes for not complex variables like int/string/double etc. there is almost no diffrence unless you doing somethign 1.000.000 times a second. If you consider that with new Element() its a diffrent story example which you can test is Vector3 in c# or any other language.
Example code in c#

```
// slowest
void functionX(){
    Vector3 newV3_0 = new Vector3();
}
// abit faster then X
Vector3 newV3_1;
void functionY(){
    newV3_1 = new Vector3();
}
// the fastest solution
Vector3 newV3_2 = Vector3.zero;
void functionZ(){
    //do things with vector;
}
// abit slower then Z
Vector3 newV3_3;
void functionQ(){
    newV3_3 = Vector3.zero;
}
```

if you gonna loop separatly each of them like 1.000.000 times functionZ will be performing the fastest cause there is nothing done inside cause you perform everything outside. But there is also a downside to this you need to remember to not use this variable in other place

Answer (score -1):

"I have tested this code and using the out of function scope variable instead of using the local variable yields better performance (albeit not by a lot in this example but there's a performance increase nonetheless)." I think this calls for a performance rant:
https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ While you did part 1 (hopefully in way that gives meaningfull results), 2-6 still apply for your case.

I consider readability, then robustness the most important things. A lot of micro optimisations (dead code dection, making functions internal, adding or removing temporary variables) can be left to the JiT. If you somehow actually do **need** that difference, then there is a 99% case you are doing [Realtime Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing). And for all it's power, realtime programming is not a strenght of the .NET Framework. Just having a Garbage Collector is usually a disqualifier.

Comment: I know where you're coming from, perhaps the reason you think I don't need the performance is because most people actually don't and just think they do when even if they do get a performance increase it will be absolutely insignificant for what they're trying to do. My oversimplified code doesn't help either.The fact is I'm making a minecraft style game where you have infinite terrain and a theoretically infinite number of npcs, so yes in my case particularly, performance is king, more so than anything else.

Comment: @Devez Did you read the article? There is also a memory consumption. In When you use local variables, the memory usage will be only when needed; for class member the variables will be there all the time with the class and therefore it can and will lead to bigger memory usage. It is acceptable? Will not the big memory usage cause slowdown when it becomes outside of standard bounds?

Comment: @Julo actually I think the opposite is true here. I did not read all of the article, but did you read my code? You think creating 10000 instances of a local variable just to set it to 0 is more memory efficient than instantiating it once and just setting its value to 0 at the start of every function call? I don't think so. My testing results don't think so either. The 2nd loop is almost twice as fast as the first.

Comment: @Devez Minecraft (like any server game or simulation) works based on massive paralelizsation and segmentation. Your approach to squeeze out perforamce this way is doomed to fail. It is not nearly fast enough. https://wiki.vg/Chunk_Format